# Incorporating scalar covariate in regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a set of subjects, each associated with a data vector $\mathbf{y}$ and a scalar covariate $z$. To each $y$ corresponds an $x$, and I wish to regress $y$ on $x$ across subjects: domain knowledge tells me that this association exists. To my surprise, on top of this association, I observe strong differences between subjects (see examples below).

[image: Example of y and z for two subjects.]

When I run `lm(y ~ x)` by subject (this was just a quick approximation), I find that the coefficient of $x$ correlates very well with that subject's $z$ value.

Hence my question: is there a way of running the regression across all subjects incorporating $z$ among the predictors?

I am confused as to how that would actually be implemented in R: per subject, $x$ and $y$ are both vectors while $z$ is a scalar, so `lm(y ~ x + z)` wouldn't fly. Not only that, but $z$ is more or less a multiple of the slope of `y ~ x`. How can this information be encoded, with an eye towards polynomial expansions?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about [tag:multiple-regression].  Are you trying to distinguish your problem somehow?

Comment: It may be multiple regression, thank you for the clarification. One issue I face, however, is how to specify this model in R: there are N (x, y) pairs per subject, but a single z per subject.